# Accept chrome payments without Chrome Web Store Payments

Tags: google-chrome, payment, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I’m developing an app for Google Chrome and I would like to know how I can charge for it.

The problem is that I live on Brazil and on this link it tells that it doesn’t support the Chrome Web Store Payments. There is other way I can charge for that without the Chrome web store payment?

https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/pricing#seller

My initial idea is to create a hosted app that is free (but limited) and the customer pays and can use it fully. Or the other idea is to give 30 days to try and the costumer need to pay only onetime if he likes it and can use it fully.

Do you guys know how to do that living in a country not supported by Chrome Web Store Payments?

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the text on https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/pricing#seller which says "In the future, we expect to support sales to the following additional regions: Argentina, Brazil, India, Mexico, and Poland. Buyers in unsupported regions might be able to purchase apps, but they can't pay in their local currency and might have to pay international transaction fees."? Not sure if that means it would work for you or not.

Otherwise I'm pretty sure you're allowed to use other payment processors other than Chrome Web Store Payments (see https://ssl.gstatic.com/chrome/webstore/intl/en/dev_tos_text.html and https://ssl.gstatic.com/chrome/webstore/intl/en/program_policies.html), so you might see if other services like PayPal, Amazon payments, etc. are a better option for you.